# Is using 是 correct in “我也是又累又渴”

Tags: grammar

In order to use adjectives as the predicate of a sentence, we don't use 是 as far as I know. For example, we say
我很累 Not 我是累
So, when using 又...又...structure, it seems to me that I should say "我也又累又渴"
or something like that and not use 是.

So, is it correct to say “我也是又累又渴”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how we use it. 我是累 can be valid in some context to clarify the fact that I am truly tired. E.g. 你是不是累了? 我是累(了).

Similarly, 我也是又累又渴 can also be valid in a context like A: 我是又累又渴 B: 我也是又累又渴.

Without previous context, we can say 我又累又渴. It's generally saying I'm tired and thirsty. It's not for clarification or anything.

So, this use of 是 is for clarification or emphasis. It would be a misuse of it when we don't need to clarify anything.

PS. As comments suggested below, in 我是又累又渴, 是 can be used either for emphasis or for a normal connecting word.

Comment: +1 Well said. And you may want to add that in this case, 是 must be stressed (必须重读).

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi it's true that in  我是累 or 我是又累又渴, 是usually needs to be stressed (to emphasize), but in 我**也是**又累又渴, it's different.  是in this sentence is not for emphasis. There **could** be tone of speaking 我也是又累又渴 with 是for emphasis, but I cannot come up with any such tone off the top of my head.

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi (and to dan as well) reading your answer/comment above twice, I realized there could be some subtle misunderstanding about the 是 in 我是又累又渴 and 我也是又累又渴. It's true that in 我是又累又渴, 是could mean to emphasize, but it could also just mean "is" (without stress, actually the opposite: in colloquial people say this 是 in 轻声). And in 我也是又累又渴, 是could NOT mean to emphasize. I am a native speaker so I am relatively confident about these comments although I am not so sure about the grammar/rule behind it.

Comment: To be more clear and also to answer the question of the OP, you cannot use 我是饿 to mean "I am hungry", but you can use 我是又累又渴or我也是又累又渴 to mean "I am tired and thirsty" or "I am also tired and thirsty" (是is unstressed in both cases). The reason behind it that I can think of, is that 又累又渴is like a noun (maybe 独立结构?), unlike 累alone (as an adjective), and therefore can follow 是(with the meaning of "am", not for emphasis). You guys probably can analyze better than me even though I am a native speaker.

Comment: @ALife You are right. 我是又累又渴 can be as neutral as 我又累又渴. And it can also be emphatic when we stress 是. So, in this case, tone plays an important role.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can totally use it. It is equal to "am" in this sentence

我(I) 也(also) 是(am) 又累又渴(tired and thirsty)

I'm also tired and thirsty

In the meantime, 我也又累又渴 is totally fine too. You can use both.

Comment: I think you are right. This is probably a simpler, short, and correct answer, assuming my comments in another answer are correct.